# PropertyConfigurator.configure multiple log4j files

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j, servlet-filters

I have two web applications(Proj1 and Proj2).

The log4j.properties file is at an external location(Say C:\proj1_log4j.properties and C:\proj2_log4j.properties)

There are Servlet Filters for both the above web applications for initializing log4j. The code is written in the init() method of both the filters.

The log4j is initialized as follows **for Proj1** (filename=Proj1Filter.java)

```
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    final String LOG_CONFIG_FILE = "C:/proj1_log4j.properties";
    File loggingPropFile = new File(LOG_CONFIG_FILE);
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(loggingPropFile);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fis);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
        LOGGER.info("Logger 111 initialiZed successfully...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The log4j is initialized as follows **for Proj2** (filename=Proj2Filter.java)

```
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    final String LOG_CONFIG_FILE = "C:/proj2_log4j.properties";
    File loggingPropFile = new File(LOG_CONFIG_FILE);
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(loggingPropFile);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fis);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
        LOGGER.info("Logger 222 initialized successfully...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**proj1_log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout1, proj1

log4j.appender.stdout1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout1.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.proj1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.proj1.File=proj1.log
log4j.appender.proj1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.proj1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.proj1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.proj1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**proj2_log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout1, proj2

log4j.appender.stdout1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout1.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.proj2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.proj2.File=proj2.log
log4j.appender.proj2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.proj2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.proj2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.proj2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

---

Now on starting tomcat, only proj1.log is getting created.
proj2.log is not getting created.
All the logs are going to proj1.log.
Even logger statements from proj2 are printing logs in proj1.log file.

What could be the reason.

What I want is, 2 log files should be created, proj1.log and proj2.log.

Answer (score 0):

You keep both the appenders `proj1 & proj2` in a single file along with the below changes.

To route project specific logging

```
log4j.logger.com.<project1_root_package> =DEBUG, proj1
log4j.logger.com.<project2_root_pacakge> =DEBUG, proj2
```

And to avoid duplication of the logs set additivity.

```
log4j.additivity.com.<project1_root_package>=false
log4j.additivity.com.<project2_root_pacakge>=false
```

and finally your root loggers becomes something like

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout1, proj1, proj2
```

Comment: Thanks Bhargav. But what if root package of the both projects happen to be same, then ?

Comment: You can dig till it reaches a stage where both will differ and mention it.

Comment: Well, all my modules in the project have same package structure, so this would be impossible for me to do :(

Comment: Its a bad practice to have different modules have same package structure..You better correct it :D

Comment: Well, id love to.. But, at the moment, that cant be done. :)

Comment: In that case, you can still go till class name and pass it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114344/discussion-between-user1771680-and-bhargav-kumar-r).